# Anylogic - Pull Source

Tags: anylogic

is it possible to have a source with Pull behaviour? That is f.e., to create an Agent when there is no more agents to Process in the system.

I'm testing how this software works in completelly pull systems.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is whenever your system is empty, inject a new agent...

```
source.inject(1);
```

This code will do the "pull" behavior, by adding a new agent in your source whenever you need to.

Comment: Thank you Felipe. That was the solution. I also included in the "Main" node the creation of a new agent at the beginning, to start the pull process.